# Delete From Folder and Database - php

Tags: php

Please help for fix the problem:

> Notice: Undefined variable: id in D:\MyWebSite\css_pro\admin\core\de_products_test.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: id in D:\MyWebSite\css_pro\admin\core\de_products_test.php on line 17

code:

```
session_start();
require("../../inc/con_db.php");

$qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);

if($row["img_thumb"]!="") {  
  $thum=$row["img_thumb"];
  unlink("/images/products/thumbs/".$thum);
}

if($row["img_larg"]!="") {  
  $larg=$row["img_larg"];
  unlink("/images/products/".$larg);
}

$delete="DELETE FROM products WHERE id='$id' ";
$result=mysql_query($delete);

if($result==1) {
  print "Entry delete success";
} else {
  print "Entry delete failed";
}
```

Comment: where do you define $id? as it states $id is undefined. You are not using register-globals are you?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the $id variable by using

```
if(isset($id))
{
     // your query
}
```

Comment: but image still not delete on directory.

Comment: the path you providing for image is correct or not, check this.

Comment: Yes, the image path is correct. Can you make for example for please.